# Connecting Sql Server DB To Fcm Notifications

Tags: sql-server, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm Developing Xamarin.forms app for both android and iOS.
and I'm connecting the app with Sql Server DB.
so I need to notifying the apps after a user insert a record using the trigger after insert and that trigger needs to speak with the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to notify the other users.
I did create a demo for connecting the app with a FCM using this tutorial playlist [Implement Push Notifications with FCM and Xamarin.Forms](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfbOp004UaYX5B2pKKp5j7QPniyLMPkSO)

and I'm also able to make the DB trigger.
but I'm struggling with how to make my sql server speaks to fcm after (trigger after insert) to notify the user.
I apologize if my question seemed naive, but I did a lot of research reading a lot of Docs but I can't figure out how to do this.

so if anyone can suggest a tutorial video or article for this issue it will be appreciated.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Opinion: you should never consume the SQL Server using your Mobile Application! You should have created the Web API or anything interfaces that can execute the DB Operation and your so-called Push notifications as well... 

Now to be specific to your question: SQL Server cannot directly talk to any other interfaces like FCM. I guess you can create CLR Assemblies to do that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/assemblies-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Assemblies%20are%20DLL%20files%20used,instead%20of%20in%20Transact%2DSQL.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi
thanks for you quick answer, but it didn't help me much.
my question again is how to connect Sql Server (Trigger after insert) and to push that trigger as a notification for my apps using the Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: In simple terms (forget about the opinion I provided in my previous comment): You said you connected your app to SQL Server database? And you probably executing the query from app to insert the record? Then after you get the result back from your insert operation in your app, you want to call your push notification interface right there, why your SQL Server needs to call your push interface!.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi 
forgive my ignorance, I've never worked with this kind of feature beyond simple app to learn the concept, but never a real-World app.
so, I'm really struggling even in searching or reading docs because I have no background.
so, if you can suggest any article / video to make me fully understand this to make the right decision, then I'll be more than happy saving time and effort and it'll be really appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Best thing you can learn first is ASP.NET Core Web API. You can find many examples if you search that online. From there you can connect to your DB, you can send push notifications, etc.. 
Then you can consume the API from your mobile application... That's how real world application works!

This video that you followed has the basic example you are looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VI1wgekz5ZM&list=PLfbOp004UaYX5B2pKKp5j7QPniyLMPkSO&index=4